# GEOS assertion failed

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, geos

The following script fails, if I import the 'rasterstats' library.

```
import rasterstats
import ogr

geom1 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POLYGON ((415924.806155724043492 4489457.402624096721411,416359.905146608769428 4489457.402624096721411,416359.905146608769428 4488983.206433195620775,415924.806155724043492 4488983.206433195620775,415924.806155724043492 4489457.402624096721411))')
geom2 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POLYGON ((415924.806155724043492 4488989.295723957009614,416795.004137493495364 4489457.402624096721411,416784.428755077067763 4488509.010242293588817,415924.806155724043492 4488989.295723957009614))')

print geom1.Intersection(geom2)
```

The error I get is:

```
Assertion failed: (pts), function testInvariant, file ../../include/geos/geomgraph/Edge.h, line 88.
```

The line causing the problem is `geom1.Intersection(geom2)`

Unfortunately there is not more error code to it. If I don't import `rasterstats`, then I don't get the error.
 What could be the reason for that behavior?

---

[Line 88 in Edge.h](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/38b479b73be2535925e268ec6a5a0af0a278f364/include/geos/geomgraph/Edge.h#L88) in GEOS is the following function:

```
void testInvariant() const {
    assert(pts);
    assert(pts->size() > 1);
}
```

What does this function test for?

---

GDAL Version 
1.10.0100

Rasterstats Version
0.3.3

GEOS Version
3.4.2-3

---

Edits:

Originally I thought it is related to Flask, but I was able to isolate the problem, and figured it is not related to Flask.

OGR exceptions doesn't give any additional error.

Comment: Are you certain your app is using the same GEOS library version? Can you turn on GDAL exceptions (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#PythonbindingsdonotraiseexceptionsunlessyouexplicitlycallUseExceptions) to catch that error?

Comment: I am fairly sure the app is using the same GEOS library because I run it local in a virtual environment. Thanks for the hint with the GDAL exceptions. I am playing around with that right now, but currently if I turn on GDAL/OGR exceptions, the script seems to freeze. It doesn't spit out anything (no error), but it also doesn't finish. I have to kill terminal to end the process.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue that the script freezes when OGR exceptions are turned on. It was caused by the rasterstats library which we fixed now. But OGR exceptions doesn't give me any additional error than the one I posted above.

Comment: Does the error still happen if you import `ogr` before `rasterstats`?

Comment: The error doesn't happen if I import `ogr` before `rasterstats`. That's strange. What's the reason for that?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I'm using the same versions of GDAL, rasterstats and shapely. It might be related to GEOS version? (I'm testing on 3.3.8)